# Display html list in curve

Tags: html, css

How to display a list in curve instead of in line block, with html and css?

[image: the final result looks like]

For easy to answer this question, I have a `codepen` prepared already

[CodePen Link](http://codepen.io/atom2ueki/pen/eNdxQG)

Many Thanks.

Comment: Are there a fixed number of items in the list, or do you need this to work with lists of any length?

Comment: @mpadittech It should be any length, my front end Angular ng-repeat should fit this effect

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this with a variable sized list, without using javascript

Comment: @mpadittech if javascript applied?

Comment: @mpadittech something like `foreach{$('#lists').css({ transform: 'rotate('+(currentAngle-20)+'deg)'});}` if I want 20 degree off fir each changes

Comment: That would cover the rotation (your selector would be $('#movies li') though), but you would also need to set top and left position of each, if you want them to line up in a parabolic way

Comment: All done now. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
transform: rotate(-30deg);
```

on the first list item. Use subsequently higher degrees, ending with

```
transform: rotate(30deg);
```

You can automate this with a Javascript/jQuery function easily if you need a dynamic solution that works for any number of items:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var numberOfItems = $('#movies ul li').length;
  var startAngle=-30;
  var maxOffset = 60;
  if (numberOfItems > 1) {
    var step = 60/(numberOfItems-1);
    $('#movies ul').css('margin-top', maxOffset+'px')
    $('#movies ul li').each(function(index) {
      var deg = startAngle + index * step;
        var offset = -1 * (maxOffset - 2 * Math.abs(deg));
      $(this).css({
        'top': offset+'px',
        'transform': 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'
      });
    });
  }
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXGBdg

Edit: Now includes a variable offset depending on the position in the list to make for a *"curvy"* look.